# Self not accessed by a method when called with certain methods of initialisation

Tags: python, self

When replicating a bug from a larger project on a smaller scale,  I reduced the problem to the following code:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        globals()["bar_class"].abc()

class Bar:
    def abc(self):
        self._123()

    def _123(self):
        print("something")

bar_class = Bar

Foo()
```

Which raises the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/A) YEAR 12/Computing/solution/test_selfbug.py", line 14, in <module>
    Foo()
  File "H:/A) YEAR 12/Computing/solution/test_selfbug.py", line 3, in __init__
    globals()["bar_class"].abc()
TypeError: abc() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

However, when the last lines are:

```
bar_class = Bar()

Foo()
```

The error is not raised. I'd assume that `self` was not created since the class was not initialized, and so `Bar.abc` did not have access to self when it was needed.

However, when changing the last lines to:

```
bar_class = Bar
bar_class()

Foo()
```

The same error is raised as before, self is not recognized as being a parameter to `Bar.abc` when it's called. This seems strange, since Bar is still initialized (albeit through the bar_class variable.)

To which the obvious answer would be to call `Bar` using `Bar()`, rather than holding the object as a variable before initialization. However, in the context of the larger program I need to be able to have this object as a variable for the sake of accessing it using `globals()` (which is the best way I have as of yet for the code to work in the larger program.)

My question is, then, what causes this behavior of self not being 'seen' by `bar.abc`, and how can I fix the issue of `abc()` not recognizing self while still having access to the `Bar` object through a variable?

---

***Note:*** I'm aware that changing the contents of `Foo.__init__` to `bar_class.abc()` is much simpler and is most definitely the cleanest solution to the error. However, again, within the context of the full program it's necessary to use `globals[key]` to retrieve an object.

Comment: try this bar_class = bar_class() or use bar_class = Bar()

Comment: Could the downvoter please let me know what's wrong with the question? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

`bar_class = Bar` makes an alias on the *class* `Bar`, but does not create an instance.

Since your method is not static, you cannot call it without an instance.

When you do `bar_class = Bar()`, now `bar_class` is an instance and that works.

Now:

```
bar_class = Bar
bar_class()    # this line achieves nothing
```

`bar_class` is `Bar` (a class) and the line below creates an instance that is garbage collected right afterwards: same as non-working case #1

(of course `bar_class = bar_class()` would work, but that's overkill)